# Proving that both $F_\sigma $ and $G_\delta$ sets are $\sigma $-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying an exercise of an assignment which asks to prove that both $F_\sigma $ and $G_ \delta $ sets are $ \sigma $-algebras.

Proving X belongs to $ F_\sigma $ and  $G_\delta $  and that countable union property is easy in case of $ F_\sigma $ sets . Can someone please tell how to prove  countable union property in case of  $ G_\delta $ and the property $2$ that if $A$ belongs to $S$ , then  $A$-complement also belongs to $S$ in both cases.

Comment: You should probably explain what $X$ and $S$ are since they appear here without introduction.  Also: union and intersection are complementary properties -- that should give you ideas of where to start with the $G_\delta$ proof

Comment: @postmortes can you please elaborate on how to proceed on G -$\delta$ proof and how to prove the second property of $\sigma$ algebra , ie if A belongs to See then complement of A also belong to S. I am a beginner in measure theory

Comment: What precisely is the proposed $\sigma$-algebra? Is it the set containing every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ that is both $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ simultaneously? Or is it the set containing all $G_\delta$ sets, as well as every $F_\sigma$ set?

Comment: @Theo Bendit I am really sorry for your inconvenience but our faculty is just not interested in teaching.  He didn't mentioned anything.  Just gave the statements that prove that F- $ \sigma $ and G- $ \delta $ are $ \sigma $ algebra.

Comment: @TheoBendit Since OP uses the plural 'sigma algebras' it appears he is considering two different classes.

Comment: @ Theo Bendit I mean to say there are two problems,  one is Prove that any F- $ \sigma $ set is a $ \sigma $ algebra.      And 2 nd problem is prove that every G-$ \delta$ set is a $ \sigma $ algebra

Comment: @postmortes  no Kavi  Rama murty is correct

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what you _mean_ by "both $F_\sigma $ and $G_ \delta $ sets are $ \sigma $-algebras". Give us the exact statement of the problem, without changing or leaving out a single word.

Comment: Why I'm confused:  What "both $F_\sigma $ and $G_ \delta $ sets are $ \sigma $-algebras" actually _says_ is that if $S$ is a $G_\delta$  or an $F_\sigma$ then $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. That can't be what you meant, since that's nonsense...

Comment: Whoops - looking at a comment above it appears that that _is_ what you mean. It's obviously not true that if $S$ is a $G_\delta$ then $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra! That makes no sense, because $S$ is a _set_ and a $\sigma$-algebra is a family of sets. So you must be reading the problem wrong - again, tell us _exactly_ what the problem asks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I am  really sorry for the ambiguity in problem. Also, kavi ram murthy has already  given answers. So, please don't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is FALSE. For each rational number $r$ the singleton set $\{r\}$ is both an $F_{\sigma}$ and a $G_{\delta}$. The union of these singletons,namely $\mathbb Q$, is well known to be not a $G_{\delta}$.

Comment: Your answer provides contradiction for G- $ \delta $ sets. Can you please give a contradiction or proof in support of argument for F- $ \sigma $ sets

Comment: By just taking complements in my example you see that $F_{\sigma}$ sets are not closed under countable intersections.

Comment: So, you are taking { r} . Will complement of { r} include irrational numbers or only Q\ { r} . Also , can you please why we taking complements and intersections as for $ \ sigma$ algebra we need to check countable union . Sir, I perfectly understood your example for G-$\delta $ . Can you please elaborate a bit for F-$\sigma$ sets.

Comment: $\mathbb R \setminus \{r\}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ for every rational number $r$ and the intersection of these sets is $\mathbb R \mathbb Q$ which is not an $F_{\sigma}$.

Comment: got it.  Thank you very much Sir.